# passport-facebook, serializeUser flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

Ive been studying express, passportjs and passport-facebook. The thing is, I dont know the flow of it and in the documentation I found nothing (IMO the documentation is poor). For example:

1. When is serialize and deserialize called? Every request? Or serialize is just called the first time when you log in?
2. In the serializeUser function, where does the user parameter come from?

   passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
       done(null, user._id);
     });

Comment: I had the same problem with passport and [this](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) explanation really helped, it focuses on local authentication but will hopefully make things clear

Comment: Thanks :) It helped

Comment: Don't mention it.